# python - how to fetch date of birth from 'tkcalender' library

Tags: python, tkinter

I am student and learning python.
I have been developing a python code for learning python GUI
I am using "tkinter & tkcalender" library to set and get the date of birth
I am able to select date, month and year from the calendar
But unable to get the details from the calendar and print it at desired screen location.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
from tkcalendar import *
cal = Calendar


class MyEntry:
    def display(self,clicked):
        global lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4,x,str1,str2,str3
        #str4=1
        x = self.var.get()
        str1 = self.e1.get()
        str1 = 'Name  : ' + str1
        if x == 1:
            str3 = 'Gender : Male'
        if x == 2:
            str3 = 'Gender : Female'
        str2 = clicked.get()
        lbl1 = Label(text=str1).place(x=50, y=700)
        lbl2 = Label(text="Age   : " + str2).place(x=50, y=720)
        lbl3 = Label(text=str3).place(x=50, y=740)
        #lbl4 = Label(text=cal.get_date())
        #lbl4.place(x=50,y=760)

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.f = Frame(root, height=1000, width=1000)
        self.f.propagate(0)
        self.f.pack()
        self.l1 = Label(text='Enter you name: ')
        self.l2 = Label(text='Select your age: ')
        self.l3 = Label(text='Select your gender: ')
        self.l4 = Label(text='Select your Date of Birth: ')
        self.e1 = Entry(self.f, width=25, fg='black', bg='white', font=('Ariel', 14))
        self.b1 = Radiobutton(self.f, text='Male', width=15, height=2, variable=self.var, value=1)
        self.b2 = Radiobutton(self.f, text='Female', width=15, height=2, variable=self.var, value=2)
        options = []
        for i in range(1, 101):
            options.append(i)
        clicked = StringVar()
        clicked.set("1")
        drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options)
        drop.pack()
        self.cal = Calendar(self.f, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day')
        self.cal.pack(pady=20)
        self.cal.place(x=450, y=180)
        self.a = Button(self.f, text="Submit", command=lambda:self.display(clicked))
        self.a.place(x=300, y=400)
        self.l1.place(x=50, y=25)
        self.e1.place(x=450, y=25)
        self.l2.place(x=50, y=75)
        drop.place(x=450, y=75)
        self.l3.place(x=50, y=125)
        self.b1.place(x=450, y=125)
        self.b2.place(x=600, y=125)
        self.l4.place(x=50, y=175)
mb = MyEntry(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost got it right from the commented code. You just need to add `self.` behind `cal.get_date()` since `cal` is a field of `MyEntry` class so you would get

```
lbl4 = Label(text=self.cal.get_date())
```

```
def display(self,clicked):
    global lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4,x,str1,str2,str3
    #str4=1
    x = self.var.get()
    str1 = self.e1.get()
    str1 = 'Name  : ' + str1
    if x == 1:
        str3 = 'Gender : Male'
    if x == 2:
        str3 = 'Gender : Female'
    str2 = clicked.get()
    lbl1 = Label(text=str1).place(x=50, y=700)
    lbl2 = Label(text="Age   : " + str2).place(x=50, y=720)
    lbl3 = Label(text=str3).place(x=50, y=740)
    lbl4 = Label(text=self.cal.get_date())
    lbl4.place(x=50,y=760)
```

Comment: Thank  you so much, I was confused in this part a long time and finally finished it with your help.